# will there be any difference between the output of a 555 oneshot and one made with a 74123?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, oscilloscope, multivibrator

I think there won't be any difference because the professor wants us to build both with 10 us pulse and with a duty cycle of 25%.

I didn't have enough time to build both MMV, so that's why I am asking

Comment: Because professors try to make you think... I'm betting you can't do this with half a 74123.  But you probably can with one 555.  Think about it.

Comment: actually, I built it with half 74123, but the time wasn't enough to grab a scope and see if there was any difference

Comment: Look at the datasheets and compare timing (things like propagation delays) and output levels and you will see differences.

Comment: My assumption is that the professor is asking for a pulse every 10us which has a duty cycle of 25%.  It doesn't make sense to ask for one 10us wide pulse and then specify a duty cycle.  I'd like to see your design if you managed to do that with half a 74123. I don't think it is impossible.   But it's got to me more complex then using both halves of the 74123.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the professor is pointing out that an 555 which contains 1 MMV made up of a flip-flop and 2 comparators:

[image]

Can do the work that may require both MMV's inside a 74123:

[image]

I'll leave the math to find the components up to you.